# tkinter mysql - how to get different information while using entries whith the 'fetch' method?

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

I have in my appliction an entry to enter "mysql-code" and search information from database, which is showing the typed text bye execute the entry in my treeviews. SELECT * FROM works fine and all this other "mysql-codes". It tried different things, to get different information from the database. `SELECT example1 FROM example2` with `fetchone()` works aswell. But I'm looking for a solution for my entry, where i can do `fetchall()`, `fetchmany()` and `fetchone()` all together.
I'm asking because I don't know how exactly I can manage it.

`CODE`

```
def direct_search_person(self, event):                                              # SEARCH FUNC() ////////////////////
        personen = mysql.connector.connect(user="root", host="127.0.0.1",
                                           database="PersonHobbyStadt")
        cur_person = personen.cursor()                                              # CREATE CURSOR ////////////////////
        try:
            for person in self.parent.main.person_tree.get_children():              # CLEAR TREE ///////////////////////
                self.parent.main.person_tree.delete(person)

            cur_person.execute(self.parent.navbar.info_dbsearch.get())              # EXECUTE CURSOR /////////////////// 
            person_record = cur_person.fetchall()

            for record in person_record:                                            # INSERT INTO TREEVIEW /////////////
                self.parent.main.person_tree.insert(parent="", iid=self.x,
                                                    index="end", text="Parent",
                                                    values=(record[0], record[1],
                                                            record[2], record[3],
                                                            record[4]))
                self.x += 1

            self.parent.navbar.info_dbsearch.delete(0, tk.END)                      # CLEAR ENTRY //////////////////////
        except (AttributeError, tk.TclError):
            pass
        except mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError:                             # OPEN MESSAGE BOX IF GET MYSQL ////
            self.parent.message.active_search_msg()                                 # ERROR ////////////////////////////

        personen.commit()
        personen.close()                                                            # CLOSE CONNECTION /////////////////
```

Comment: Your code has already used `fetchall()`, so what is your problem actually?

Comment: I wrote it Above. My question was how I can get different Informations into my treeview. Here In this code I get ALL informations. When I'm trying `SELECT reacord[1] FROM table` I get `IndexError`. So now I'm looking for a solution, where I can use all this functions for my entry and that shows me different `SELECTED` items or all items.

Comment: It is hard to cater different query results, for example `"SELECT A, B FROM Table"` and `"SELECT B, C, D FROM Table"` will have different result sets that you cannot present them in the already created treeview.

Comment: I have the same problem in a label and textfield. But would you say, I need to create another functions or shall I put the other (new) records to the `except method()`? My entry has the `bind` method with `"<return>"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an example to show the result of SQL query using `Treeview` which is configured based on the result dynamically.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import mysql.connector

# use your database configuration
db = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="user", password="password", database="database")

def execute_sql(event):
    sql = sqlbox.get("1.0", "end-1c")
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql)
    # configure treeview
    table.config(columns=cursor.column_names)
    for col in cursor.column_names:
        table.heading(col, text=col)
    # insert data
    table.delete(*table.get_children())
    for rec in cursor:
        table.insert("", "end", values=rec)
    cursor.close()

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1000x800")

# text box to input SQL statement
sqlbox = tk.Text(root, height=10)
sqlbox.pack(fill="x")
sqlbox.bind("<F9>", execute_sql)

# treeview to show the query result
frame = ttk.Frame(root)
frame.pack(fill="both", expand=1)

frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

table = ttk.Treeview(frame, show="headings")
table.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(frame, orient="vertical", command=table.yview)
vsb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")

hsb = ttk.Scrollbar(frame, orient="horizontal", command=table.xview)
hsb.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew")

table.config(xscrollcommand=hsb.set, yscrollcommand=vsb.set)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: can i ask you how i can show errors in the textfield?  never worked before with textfield. so with entries it works, but with this text field, something is missing = `except mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError:` `self.text.insert("1.0", "wrong syntax ... %s " % self.text.get("1.0", "end-1c"))` . it works, but i have doublicate from my text. if i type = `a` he gives me double `a a`... sorry for that question.

Comment: @JoeMo Sorry I don't get what you want.

Comment: if I have a wrong syntax, pycharm shows me that error. I want the "wrong syntax" in brackets which i typed in the text field. I don't understand the textbox insert properties. With entries it works.

Comment: @JoeMo I think you want to know how to replace the original content in the text box by new one.  Use `.delete("1.0", "end")` to clear the text box before inserting new content.

Comment: so I mean this part `% self.text.get("1.0", "end-1c"))`

Comment: I think you only need to call `.insert("1.0", "wrong syntax ... ")` which insert the error message at the beginning of the text box.

Comment: Why don't you use another label to show the warning?

Comment: i want to learn, to handle with each widgets. So if I don't figure it out (or with help), it means to me that I give up. And thats not the goal for me.