# Problem with for loop in Python tkinter code

Tags: python, for-loop, tkinter

```
import tkinter
import sqlite3
from tkinter import messagebox

def login():
    i = en_id.get()
    p = en_pw.get()

    conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM member")
    rows = cur.fetchall()
   

#-----------------------------
# NEEDS TO BE FIXED

    for row in rows:
        if row[0] == i and row[1] == p:

        # login success
            messagebox.showinfo(row[0] + '님 환영합니다 !', '로그인 성공 !')

        else:

        # login fail
            messagebox.showerror('아이디와 비번을 확인하세요', '로그인 실패 !')
            break
#-----------------------------

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

w = tkinter.Tk()
w.title('로그인 실습 v0.5')

lbl_id = tkinter.Label(w, text='아이디 : ') # id
lbl_pw = tkinter.Label(w, text='패스워드 : ') # pw
en_id = tkinter.Entry(w)
en_pw = tkinter.Entry(w)
btn_login = tkinter.Button(w, text='LOGIN')

lbl_id.grid(row=0, column=0)
lbl_pw.grid(row=1, column=0)
en_id.grid(row=0, column=1)
en_pw.grid(row=1, column=1)
btn_login.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='nswe')

w.mainloop()
```

test.db's member table consists of :

| id | pw |
| --- | --- |
| id1 | pw1 |
| id2 | pw2 |

The problem here is that if login is successful, I get a failure popup after the expected success popup. It seems like there's something wrong with the loop.
The for loop underneath # NEEDS TO BE FIXED needs improvement, please help :(

Comment: use a flag, set the flag initially to `0`/`False` then if the login credentials matches, set it to `1`/`True` and break from the loop. Now check if the flag is `1` or `0` and accordingly show the message.

Comment: See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67896179/5317403) of other question.  It uses similar for loop on login checking. Basically you need to break out the for loop once a record is found.

Comment: thanks so much everyone, will try and let you know of the results :)

Comment: here a good option to db from @acw1668. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67583188/tkinter-mysql-how-to-get-different-information-while-using-entries-whith-the

i don't realy understand your probelm.. but in rows or in colums you can use loops with `enumarate`. but your table looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to break the for loop once a record is found:

```py
def login():
    ...
    for row in rows:
        if row[0] == i and row[1] == p:
            # login success
            messagebox.showinfo(row[0] + '님 환영합니다 !', '로그인 성공 !')
            break
    else:
        # login fail
        messagebox.showerror('아이디와 비번을 확인하세요', '로그인 실패 !')
    ...
```

Note that you can simplify the checking by using different SQL statement:

```py
def login():
    ...
    cur.execute("SELECT 1 FROM member WHERE id = ? AND pw = ?", (i, p))
    row = cur.fetchone()

    if row:
        # login success
        messagebox.showinfo('님 환영합니다 !', '로그인 성공 !')
    else:
        # login fail
        messagebox.showerror('아이디와 비번을 확인하세요', '로그인 실패 !')
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the loop was that

i) If the input information matches a tuple (login credentials) that is NOT the first in rows: since the information does not match the first tuple a login fail dialog is displayed and the loop stops there (due to the break statement).

ii) If the input information matches the first tuple in rows: a login success dialog is displayed and the loop moves on to check the second tuple anyway; thus a fail dialog is shown after the success dialog before quitting the loop.

```
for row in rows:
    if row[0] == iid and row[1] == pw:
        flag = True
        break
    else:
        flag = False
```

-> Solved by using a `flag` like suggested :)

Another problem with this code is that btn.login here does not have a command to run; therefore nothing happens when the button is pressed, since login() hasn't been summoned in the first place.

```
btn_login = tkinter.Button(w, text='LOGIN', command=login)
```

-> Solved by adding `, command=login` behind `text='LOGIN'`

Entire code BEFORE revision:

```
import tkinter
import sqlite3
from tkinter import messagebox

def login():
    i = en_id.get()
    p = en_pw.get()

    conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM member")
    rows = cur.fetchall()
   

#-----------------------------
# NEEDS TO BE FIXED

    for row in rows:
        if row[0] == i and row[1] == p:

        # login success
            messagebox.showinfo(row[0] + '님 환영합니다 !', '로그인 성공 !')

        else:

        # login fail
            messagebox.showerror('아이디와 비번을 확인하세요', '로그인 실패 !')
            break
#-----------------------------

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

w = tkinter.Tk()
w.title('로그인 실습 v0.5')

lbl_id = tkinter.Label(w, text='아이디 : ') # id
lbl_pw = tkinter.Label(w, text='패스워드 : ') # pw
en_id = tkinter.Entry(w)
en_pw = tkinter.Entry(w)
btn_login = tkinter.Button(w, text='LOGIN')

lbl_id.grid(row=0, column=0)
lbl_pw.grid(row=1, column=0)
en_id.grid(row=0, column=1)
en_pw.grid(row=1, column=1)
btn_login.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='nswe')

w.mainloop()
```

Entire code AFTER revision:

```
import tkinter
import sqlite3
from tkinter import messagebox


def login():
    iid = entry_id.get()
    pw = entry_pw.get()

    if iid == "" or pw == "":
        messagebox.showwarning('빈 칸이 있습니다', '아이디와 비번을 입력해주세요') # Empty input error

    #BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    #db_path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "test")

    with sqlite3.connect('test') as con:
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM member")
        rows = cur.fetchall()
        print(rows)

        flag = False  # 로그인 성공 시 True (login success -> True)

        for row in rows:
            if row[0] == iid and row[1] == pw:
                flag = True
                break
            else:
                flag = False
        # con.commit()
        # con.close()

        # for row in rows:
        #     if row[0] == iid and row[1] == pw:
        #         messagebox.showinfo(row[0] + '님 환영합니다 !', '로그인 성공 !')
        #     else:
        #         messagebox.showerror('아이디와 비번을 확인하세요', '로그인 실패 !')
        #         break
        # con.commit()
        # con.close()

        if flag:       
            messagebox.showinfo(row[0] + '님 환영합니다 !', '로그인 성공 !')
        elif flag is False:
            messagebox.showerror('아이디와 비번을 확인하세요', '로그인 실패 !')


w = tkinter.Tk()
w.title('로그인 실습 v0.5')

lbl_id = tkinter.Label(w, text='아이디 : ')
lbl_pw = tkinter.Label(w, text='패스워드 : ')
entry_id = tkinter.Entry(w)
entry_pw = tkinter.Entry(w, show='*')

btn_login = tkinter.Button(w, text='LOGIN', command=login)

lbl_id.grid(row=0, column=0)
lbl_pw.grid(row=1, column=0)
entry_id.grid(row=0, column=1)
entry_pw.grid(row=1, column=1)
btn_login.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='nswe')

w.mainloop()
```

<sub>*Added on behalf of the question author.*</sub>